# Socket RECV stuck in loop

Tags: c++, sockets

I have the following code:

```
while (true)
{
    recv(server, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
    cout << buffer;
}
```

What I expect to happen is when my client sends data to the server for it to receive the data, output it and then go back to trying to receive more data but it never actually reaches the cout line. If I remove the loop it works fine, why is the while loop making RECV never end..?

Send code:

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> buffer;
    send(client, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide full code. Also, what makes you so sure that the line is not reached? Further, buffer seems to be a `char*` or similar, what makes you think it is zero-terminated, as required in order for `strlen()` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` is buffered, so the output is not directly visible.
Try

```
std::cout << buffer << std::flush;
```

instead.

As to why the loop never ends: by default, sockets are in blocking mode, so the `recv` will wait as long as there is some data available and only return then.
You have to move your `server` socket into non-blocking mode or just read once.

Comment: Thanks, the flush worked. But I don't fully understand why though, I get that RECV is blocking and I want it to block, but shouldn't it stop blocking once I send data to the server?

Comment: No. You mean by "send data to the server" just a `send` call, right? Why **should** it?

Comment: In Danny_ds message he mentioned it will block as long as "there is no data". By running the send function doesn't that populate the buffer with data and should therefore stop the blocking?

Comment: @user1157885 Ah, now I get it. Yes it should stop. Do you have multiple threads or multiple programs? Show us the sending code, please.

Comment: It's a separate program. The RECV section is a server app and the send one is a client app.

Comment: @user1157885 The issue isn't that recv is blocking. You receive data, recv() unblocks. Then you print it to `cout` , but since cout is buffered, nothing appears on your screen, so you just think that recv() doesn't receive anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, you always have to check the return value of [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).

Then, if you're using `std::cout` you have to make sure your `buffer` is null-terminated.

`recv()` will block as long as there is no data, or an error (or connection closed, timeout, etc) occurs.

**Update** (Send code added)

```
cin >> buffer;
```

-> your buffer could overflow here..

```
send(client, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
```

-> here also: always check the return code.